# "control myself from laugh" or "control myself from laughing"?

Tags: grammar

Context:

1. I am not able to control myself from **laugh**.
2. I am not able to control myself from **laughing**.

Comment: Either **to control myself** or **to control my laugh**. Idiomatically you can't help doing something or you can't help but to do something. In your case the suitable verb would be **to prevent**: _I was unable to prevent myself from doing something._

Comment: @MvLog - "control my *laughing*" also sounds reasonably natural to me, as does "keep from laughing".

Comment: @stangdon I've learned a rule: **if there is a choice between a noun and a gerund—use the noun.** Keep from = prevent from (the latter sounds a bit formal, I agree)

Comment: You have not provided "context," you have merely typed two versions of the same sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I would say

> I can't control my laughter

or

> I can't stop myself (from) laughing

or

> I can't stop laughing

"I am not able to" is OK", but "I am unable to" or "I cannot" is probably more natural.  However, in ordinary conversation or informal writing we would use "I can't".

Notes:

- I have assumed that your intended meaning is that you are unable to stop laughing, but "I am unable to control myself from laughing" is acceptable if your intended meaning is "I am laughing so much that I am unable to control myself" - though the latter wording might be clearer.
- There is a difference of nuance between stopping laughing (which means you have started and then stopped) and stopping yourself *from* laughing (which suggests preventing yourself from laughing at all).

References:

- Cambridge ("[stop](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stop)"; "[control](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/control)"):

> **stop** *verb* (FINISH) [ I or T ] to finish doing something that you were doing: [...] [ + *-ing verb* ] *Stop shouting - you're giving me a headache!*
>
> **stop** *verb* (PREVENT) [ T ] to prevent someone from doing something: [...] [ + *-ing verb* ] *They've put barriers up to stop people (from) getting through.*
>
> **control** *verb* [ T ] to order, limit, or rule something, or someone's actions or behaviour

Comment: to stop myself **from** laughing is correct too   Stop yourself (from) doing something  _I couldn’t stop myself laughing.  She grabbed the rail to stop herself from falling._

Comment: @MvLog Agreed.  I've edited my answer.  There's a possible difference of nuance.  You can laugh a bit but then control your laughter or stop laughing or stop yourself laughing - whereas "stopping yourself from laughing" probably means preventing yourself from laughing (at all / in the first place). In this case, "I can't stop laughing" means that you began to laugh and then tried unsuccessfully to stop, whereas "I can't stop myself from laughing" probably means you couldn't prevent yourself from starting to laugh.  "I can't stop myself laughing" could mean either.